# How to make a button visible by clicking another button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

How can I make the button `save` visible when I click the `edit` button? This is my code so far, but it happends nothing. I'm working in a jsp

```
   <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Edit" ONCLICK="btnEdit()" class="styled-button-2">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Save" ONCLICK="btnSave()" class="styled-button-2" style="visibility:hidden;" id="save">

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function btnEdit()
        {
            {document.getElementsById("save").style.visibility="visible";}

        }    
     </script>
```

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementsById`.

Comment: you also can get rid of the extra "block" created with the second level braces

Comment: please, read the [javascript conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)... your code is horrible

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/3e8rzxmf/3/)

It is considered bad practice to add `onclick` in your html, and you miss-spelled a method. You should equally avoid adding your css in your html as well.

### HTML:

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Edit" class="styled-button-2" id="edit">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Save" class="styled-button-2" id="save">
```

### JS:

```
var edit = document.getElementById("edit");
var save = document.getElementById("save");

edit.onclick = function() {
    save.style.visibility = "visible";

}
```

### CSS:

```
#save {
    visibility: "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be a long day.

You have a misspelling.

**Not right**

```
document.getElementsById
```

**Right Way**

```
document.getElementById
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("save").style.visibility="visible";
```

use getElementById not getElementsById

Answer (score 0):

Probably a simple error, but you wrote `getElementsById` not `getElementById`, which meant you were trying to get more than one element, when infact you only need to get the "save" button.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function btnEdit()
    {
        {document.getElementById("save").style.visibility="visible";}

    }    
 </script>
```

Side note: You may want to tidy your code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function btnEdit()
    {
        document.getElementById("save").style.visibility="visible";
    }    
</script>
```